# Why does my browser fail to load non-HTTPS pages/sites?

Tags: http, browsing

OS: Win 7 x64
Browser: IE v11 
ISP: BSNL

Over the last 2-3 days I am unable to open any site with a simple HTTP URL. HTTPS pages load alright. Any attempt to navigate to a page with a simple HTTP spec results initially in a message "Please wait while you are redirected". Refreshing the browser screen at this stage throws a 404.

Netstat shows me a bunch of entries for HTTP there is only this browser (<strike>FF/Onion</strike> tor) window open at the moment. These are listed below

```
  TCP    192.168.1.21:49558     relay2:9001            ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.1.21:50382     a104-95-190-9:http     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.21:50383     a104-95-190-9:http     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.21:50384     a104-95-190-9:http     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.21:50398     a104-95-190-16:http    TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.21:50404     a104-95-190-16:http    TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.21:50405     a104-95-190-16:http    TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.21:50406     a104-95-190-16:http    TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.21:50407     a184-27-56-56:http     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.21:50408     a104-95-190-9:http     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.21:50409     a184-27-56-56:http     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.21:50410     a184-27-56-56:http     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    192.168.1.21:50411     a184-27-56-56:http     SYN_SENT
```

Additional detail:

This may/may not be pertinent. Windows Updates no longer display progress; the progress bar shows 0% all the while. Same with Microsoft Security Essentials update & definition update

My questions

- Why does my browser fail to load non-HTTPS pages/sites?
- How do I resolve the above problem?

Comment: Does it work if you disable the Onion extension?

Comment: @Paul: My apologies; it's tor. Afaik - impossible to disable.

Comment: I guess this perhaps more of a Tor issue? If so it should be tagged as such

Comment: @barlop: The issue manifested in IE where any **non-HTTPS** URL resulted in a "Please wait while you are redirected". On the other hand and at the same time IE loaded sites over an HTTPS link without issue.

Comment: @Everyone and you cannot disable TOR so who knows. Is your issue different to this one http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/8813/cant-access-http-non-ssl-sites-with-tor-browser  which i'd note nobody has answered

Comment: @barlop: This issue differs from the one you linked to. IE, my default browser, presenting a "Please wait while you are redirected" for any site over HTTP is the issue.